# Can I change the order of search in Outlook email messages?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook-2003

XP Outlook 2003.

When I want to find a message containing a phrase, Outlook searches from the earliest message.
However, usually the message I want is quite recent.

*Is there a way to change the order in which Outlook 2003 searches email messages?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook searches based on modified date - oldest first, that's why it finds the oldest messages first.

Comment: I understand that. My question is, "How can I change that"? Regards,

Comment: I don't think it can be changed, at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: It appears that you are right - it cannot be changed. Therefore you get the acceptance.  I did find a workaround that has helped me, and that is to use "Search Folders": http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/about-search-folders-HP007328474.aspx.  Regards,

Comment: @Xavierjazz: Thanks and thanks for the heads up regarding Search Folders.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the Date column, isn't there a sort-by filter? (Newest on Top etc.) That would be my first guess. I'm running Outlook 2010 however, so maybe it's different.

Comment: There is on the entire set of messages, but I can see no way to change the order os search of those messages.

Comment: Well, here are some other options: (a) Upgrade Outlook (I really like 2010 - it is fast and much more efficient with large inboxes. Has built-in "live" search). (b) Install Google Desktop and use it to search your Inbox. It is very fast and has numerous sort / filter options.

Answer (score 0):

Alleluia.

I am still  using Outlook 2007 and searching was painful because it searched the oldest first (2004 in my case) and displayed the newest last. By unchecking the folders check boxes in Instant Search, results are displayed instantly  with the most recent first.

What was the point of instant search?!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).